# Могла ли материнская плата перегореть от работы HDD?

Tags: железо, hdd, ноутбук, hp

Доброго времени суток.
Очень странный вопрос образовался.

Установил в ***ноутбук*** HDD 2.5", через неделю перегорела материнская плата(ноутбук просто стоял на столе, работал, но его никто не трогал).

Симптомы: не работает ничего, даже светодиоды, но при подключении батареи/кабеля питания греется процессор и некоторые диоды. Греются так, что воду вскипятить можно т.е работе не подлежит.

Собственно вопрос: могут ли быть эти события как-то связаны? может усиление тока стало причиной? Технические детали ниже, если это как-то поможет.

Ноутбук: HP Elitebook 850 G3

Материнская плата: 
HP - http://partsurfer.hp.com/ShowPhoto.aspx?partnumber=826807-001 Магазин - http://allegro.pl/826807-001-hp-840-g3-850-g3-i7-6500u-100-sprawna-i7033918021.html

Comment: Может и связаны: коротнули что-то в процессе установки, например.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов через неделю почти беспрерывной работы? так бывает?

Comment: Новую мамку поставил, три часа, полет нормальный. Будем смотреть